# How to programmatically set global form error in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I have a function which appends server (remote) errors to the fields in my form.
How can I add global errors to the form (i.e not just one field)?
I marked it with TODO

```
import {NgForm} from 'angular2/common';

export function appendRemoteErrorsToForm(form: NgForm, modelState: Map<string, Array<string>>) {
  if (!modelState) {
    return;
  }
  let _globalKey = 'global';
  for (let key in modelState) {
    let errors = modelState[key];
    if (key !== 'global') {
      form.controls[key].setErrors({
        remote: errors
      });
    } else {
      //todo
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would set the error on the `ControlGroup` associated with the `NgForm` directive:

```
for (let key in modelState) {
  let errors = modelState[key];
  if (key !== 'global') {
    form.controls[key].setErrors({
      remote: errors
    });
  } else {
    form.control.setErrors({ // <-----
      remote: errors
    });
  }
}
```

This way you will be able to reference it this way:

```
<form #companyForm="ngForm">
  <div *ngIf="companyForm.control.errors">
    Display errors
  </div>
</form>
```